# How to specify a resource on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I am having trouble getting Spring to read an applicationContext.xml file from my classpath.

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
```

and

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

cause the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main"  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
[applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
```

The following code correctly lists all of the jar files that are on my classpath including the one with the applicationContext file.

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for(URL url: urls){System.out.println(url.getFile());}
```

One of these jars has a *resources* folder that contains my "applicationContext.xml" file. I have opened the jar file with 7-Zip to be sure that it is there.

I added some code to try to see if the classloader that listed my jar files could find it.

```
URL appContextURL=cl.getResource("applicationContext.xml");
if(appContextLocation==null){
    logger.info("context not found in classpath");
}else{
    logger.info("Application context found at " + appContextLocation);
}
```

This does not find it either.

What do I have to do to make sure that the applicationContext.xml is found?

Comment: where have you put your applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: If that has a `resources` folder then your path should be `/resources/applicationContext.xml` what you have now will load it from the root of the classpath.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.
None of the examples that I found had to do this so I guess that this is a result of using Maven to do the build

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to fix the relative path to include the folder as M. Deinum suggested.

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:resources/applicationContext.xml");
```

and in the debugging

```
URL appContextURL=cl.getResource("applicationContext.xml");
```

This need did not appear in any of the examples that I found on-line so I gather that this structure is a result of using defaults in Eclipse and Maven while building the jars.

Thanks to everyone for the great questions and suggestions.